# Array Out of Index Error?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm using some new methods that I don't usually use(random.nextInt()), so help is greatly appreciated.

```
  int[][] A = new int[100][100];
  private void room()
  {
    int xCo = random.nextInt(92);
    int yCo = random.nextInt(92);
    int xCoPLUS = random.nextInt(7);
    int yCoPLUS = random.nextInt(7);
    for(int across = xCo; across < across+xCoPLUS; across++) 
    {
      for(int vert = yCo; vert < vert+yCoPLUS; vert++)
      {
        A[vert][across] = 1;
      }
    }
  }
```

I'm getting the error at the line A[vert][across] = 1;

A[][] is 100 by 100.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Is declared in the class this method is located; I'll add it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you really mean:

```
for(int across = xCo; across < xCo+xCoPLUS; across++) 
{
   for(int vert = yCo; vert < yCo+yCoPLUS; vert++)
   {
      A[vert][across] = 1;
   }
}
```

Note the change I made to your loop conditions, as `across < across + xCoPLUS` will always be true, at least until you get an integer overflow :)

Answer (score 0):

The loop conditions `across < across+xCoPLUS` and `vert < vert+yCoPLUS` will always stay true given `xCoPLUS` and `yCoPlus` are non-zero, thus your loops will loop indefinitely, thus walking past the end of the array.